# A bounded function of the packing and covering density of lattices

Tags: geometry-of-numbers, euclidean-lattices

Given a (finite-dimensional) lattice $L$ of an Euclidean vector-space, the function 
$$L\longmapsto -\log(\hbox{packing density of }L)/
\log(\hbox{covering density of }L)$$
is bounded and bounded away from $0$ if restricted to all lattices
of a given dimension $d$.

What are the local minima and maxima (if there are any) of this function?